# in a certain directory check which files have a certain name prefix and remove that same prefix

Tags: c#, console-application

In this folder i have .OK files and .text files and i have to rename those files that contain this prefix ('error_')  BUT in a specific order, first  delete the prefix of the .text files , and then delete the prefix of all my .OK files, in this particular order.

This code below partially solves my problem,but it will replace with "" all the files that contain the "Error_" prefix at once

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyPath");
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach(FileInfo f in infos)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace("Error_",""));
}
```

Comment: This is not clear. can you put a simple small list of file names, you expect to find, and show us the end result

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only rename file with the extension of .OK and .text, if u would like to do it in order, you may have two for loops for each "if" condition:

```
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyPath");
        FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
        {
            if (f.FullName.EndsWith(".OK") || f.FullName.EndsWith(".text"))
                File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace("Error_", ""));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily move the file. by first deleting the file with same name

```
File.Delete(f.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the `.txt` files before the `.OK` files then you can order the `FileInfo[]` data in the foreach loop

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\temp");

FileInfo[] fileInfos = di.GetFiles();
foreach(var f in fileInfos.OrderByDescending(f => f.Extension))
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
}
```

This will iterate over the `.txt` files first and then the '`OK` files.

If you want to be more specific then you can use a `Where` to filter them:

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = di.GetFiles();
foreach(var f in fileInfos.Where(f => f.Extension == ".txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
}
```

You can refactor that code to make it reusable for different extensions :-)

Comment: hello this is quite useful. So you are saying that fileInfos.OrderByDescending(f => f.Extension)) is going to rename first the .txt files and then the .OK files?

Comment: Yes, because in descending order .txt comes before .Ok :-)